# Why isn't this CSS3 animation working in Safari & Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, animation, css

I used the -webkit- stuff and it doesn't animate for some reason, even though the same code with -moz- prefix works in firefox.

The background is meant to slide down, then the background changes & the new animation should start. The new animation is the same, the background slides in, then slides down out of the box, then the new one comes in again.

http://jsfiddle.net/6sQTJ/

Comment: Just use pixels everywhere instead of mixing percentages and pixels. Since the element has a fixed height this should not be a problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/6sQTJ/5/ for a working example. (PS it would be nice if you added the part of the code that doesn't work to the question)

Comment: @Gerben wow so it was because of the % and pixels mixed. That was the code that didn't work... (it works in firefox with the -moz-animation and @-moz-keyframes) but it wasn't animating in -webkit- browsers.

Comment: @Gerben but its fine now so thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer, given by @Gerben, was that you can't mix % positions with pixel 'px' positions in the CSS3 animation. Even though it will work in FireFox, it won't work in some other CSS3-animation-enabled browsers.